# Two UITextFields With same Hiding Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Hello I'm trying to have two of my UITextFields' keyboards hide when the user clicks off of the keyboard. I need both of my textfields to have the same method. How can I do this without duplicating them and giving Xcode and error? 
Thanks!

Here's the method I'm using for my first textfield I need the same for my other.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([text1 isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != text1) {
        [text1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple strongly recommends to use gesture recognizers, not touchesBegan and other "touches" methods if you do not really have to use them.

Try this code. It will work for any numbers of text views inside view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onBackgroundTapped)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
... another initialization code
}

- (void)onBackgroundTapped
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```